# Passing Variables across 2 views/controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a 2 page sign-up form whereby the user first enters their email and password using the `UsersController`, then directed to a second page for personal information (e.g. name, age) using the `DetailsController`. The two tables are linked in a one-to-one relationship.

How do I pass the `user_id` field from the `UsersController` to the `DetailsController` so I can keep the relationship?

`User.first` has been hard coded in the example. But, I want to pass the new `user_id` into the `@detail.user` variable.

```
def create
  @detail = Detail.new(detail_params)
  @detail.user = User.first
  if @detail.save 
    flash[:notice] = "Your Details has been successfully saved"
    redirect_to detail_path(@detail)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways to implement this is to make `Detail` as nested resource of `User`:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources :details
end
```

Then a route for a new detail page will look like this: `/users/:user_id/details/new`. It will allow you to redirect user to step 2 page from a `create` action in `UsersController`:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def create
# ...
if @user.save
  redirect_to new_details_path(user_id: @user.id)
else
  render 'new'
end
```

In your DetailsController you will able to obtain `user_id` from params:

```
# app/controllers/details_controller.rb
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @detail = @user.detail.build(detail_params)
  # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions. They are free. Example =>
`session[:foo] = 'bar'`

and you can access it on the next page like this `session[:foo]`. If you want to clear the session, just set it to nil.